# Magento 1.9.0.1 admin not working after SUPEE-8788

Tags: magento-1.9, patches, supee-8788

I am using Magento 1.9.0.1. When i applied SUPEE-8788 from command line then it was throwing error `ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.`

Then I cleaned cache and try to login in `admin` but it is not logging and showing below error.

```
The example.com page isn’t working

example.com is currently unable to handle this request.

HTTP ERROR 500
```

Can anyone help me how to solve this ?

Comment: seems permission error.

Comment: Which folder i need to give permission ??

Comment: admin login page is coming but when i insert username and password after that it's throwing 500 internal server error.

Comment: set 755 recursively for folders and 644 for files. And together with above, no other errors are showing? like showing error in a file specifically?

Comment: No, I enabled error report also but it's not showing any error.

Comment: did you set permissions like i said?

Comment: Yes, i set permission but still same issue and when i tried like `http://example.com/dashboard/index/index` then its showing **ERROR** `Warning: ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given  in /home/devppex/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/newpump/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml on line 68`

Comment: In your `index.php` file, change `#ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to `ini_set('display_errors', 1);`, refresh page. You will see the errors. Debug it or post your error details in your question.

Comment: I already have `error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
  ini_set('display_errors', 1);
  $_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'] = true;
` in my index.php but still it is not showing error @JaiminSutariya

Comment: Have you check applied.patches.list ?

Comment: Have you install the patch or not, you didn't clarify this in your question.

Comment: checked with developer mode on?

Comment: from terminal patch was not applied. So , i did it by copy paste all files and folder. Now . fontend showing this **ERROR-** `Warning: ksort() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given  in /home/devppex/public_html/app/design/frontend/default/newpump/template/page/html/topmenu.phtml on line 68
`

Comment: Do you follow these parameters ---> NOTE: if you have installed version 1 of the patch, it is recommended to do the following:
Revert SUPEE-8788 v1/
Revert SUPEE-1533 (if installed)
Install SUPEE-3941 (if not installed yet)
Install SUPEE-8788 v2

Comment: I am trying to revert 1533 but it not reverting 
`ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Dashboard/Graph.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php
Hunk #1 FAILED at 92.
1 out of 1 hunk FAILED -- saving rejects to file app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/DashboardController.php.rej
`

Comment: Have you try this now or before because you have said you have manually installed 8788 patch that's why error is showing

Comment: I think you should have backup of your files you should follow all the steps and try again to install 8788

Comment: Yes, i have backup. I will try from starting

Answer (score 2):

> **If you backup of your site, please upload backup,the site will come
>   back as it as before.**
>
> First check your website previous patches install or not on this URL http://magereport.com/  If not
>   install yet please follow below sequence and install first these patches after SUPEE-8788.
>
> SUPEE-7405, SUPEE-6788, SUPEE-6482, SUPEE-6285, SUPEE-5994,
>   SUPEE-5344, SUPEE-3941
>
> New SUPEE-8788v2 patch can be downloaded as usual from Downloads page:
>   https://magento.com/tech-resources/downloads/magento/
>
> NOTE: if you have installed version 1 of the patch, it is recommended
>   to do the following:
>
> Revert SUPEE-8788 v1/
>
> Revert SUPEE-1533 (if installed)
>
> Install SUPEE-3941 (if not installed yet)
>
> Install SUPEE-8788 v2
>
> For More Information please visit on this URL:-
>   https://magentary.com/kb/install-supee-8788/